# modified intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Given f : [a, b] $\to$ R, and f is continous we know if f(a) < 0 and f(b) > 0, then $\exists$ c $\in$[a, b] such that f(c) = 0.

The following is my proof.

Proof by contradiction:
case 1 : f(c) < 0
let S = {x$\in$[a, b] : f(x) < 0}. Since S is bounded so let c = sup(S). 
Since f is continuous at c, $\exists$ $\delta$ > 0 such that $\forall$ x $\in$ (c - $\delta$, c + $\delta$) we have f(x) < 0. 
Thus, sup(S) > c + $\delta$ > c which is a contradiction

case2 : f(c) > 0:
by continuity we got $\forall$ x : x$\in$ [c - $\delta$, c + $\delta$]  we have f(x) > 0.
Thus, we have sup(S) < c $\delta$ which contradicts to c = sup(S).

Now, if I let f(a) > 0 and f(b) < 0, would theorem still hold?
if yes, will the proof be exactly the same?

Comment: You can apply the theorem on $g(x) =-f(x) $.

Comment: could u be more specific? Why do we need the conversion g(x) = -f(x)?

Comment: You haven't quite stated the theorem correctly.  You need $f$ to be continuous.  You do acknowledge this requirement in your proof so I know you realize this, but as a matter of pedagogy and communication it's good to be precise throughout your writing.  Otherwise people who are unfamiliar with the subject will have trouble reconciling the disconnect between the statement of the theorem (which doesn't require continuity) and its proof (which uses continuity).

Comment: @Paramanand Singh If I use the conversion like you said, will the proof be exactly the same?

Comment: It appears you did not get my point. Your proof in question applies to all continuous functions on $[a, b] $ which take negative value at $a$ and positive value at $b$. Now you are given a function $f$ continuous on $[a, b] $ but $f(a) >0,f(b)<0$. In that case define a new function $g$ by $g(x) =-f(x) $ then $g$ is continuous and $g(a) <0,g(b)>0$. Now your proof applies to function $g$ and gives a $c\in(a, b) $ with $g(c) =0$. This means that $f(x) =-g(c) =0$ and thus the theorem works in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the theorem holds in that case too and proof is not exactly same but similar.

A better approach is to state the theorem as follows:

> **Intermediate Value Theorem (for continuous functions)**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a function such that it is continuous on $[a, b] $ and $f(a) f(b) <0$ (ie $f(a), f(b) $ are of opposite signs). Then there is a $c\in(a, b) $ with $f(c) =0$.

You can start your proof like:

> Let's assume that $f(a) <0,f(b)>0$ (the case $f(a) >0,f(b)<0$ follows from the one being considered by applying it to $-f$ instead of $f$).

Or

> Without any loss of generality we can assume $f(a) <0,f(b) >0$

(and let the readers or examiners figure out why there is no loss of generality involved in the above assumption).

In general proofs can and should be made concise by omitting trivial and obvious details which can be supplied easily by a reader himself in his mind. The practice is not to omit the details entirely but to mention it in a sentence briefly indicating how the details can be filled if needed.